# Eight point circle: why are all conditions met, but the points are not as expected?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I was trying to draw the eight point circle for a convex quadrilateral. The only condition that I know of is that it must be a convex quadrilateral with perpendicular diagonals.

This is a picture of a successful construction using GeoGebra. I constructed it by first constructing perpendicular diagonals (that is BG and FH) then completing the quadrilateral from there on.

[image: 8-point circle]

Even if we vary the length of line segment EH, the diagonals will still be perpendicular (as all angles at E are perpendicular), and taking care it remains a convex quadrilateral, I arrived at the following:

[image: putative 8-point circle, but with two points missing]

Where did the other few points go? Am I missing some other conditions?

Comment: If you extend $GH$ and $BH$, you will get the other two points you want.

Comment: @Yourong 'DZR' Zang Oh wait, so the definition of eight point circle includes the case where the lines need to be extended? Oops. Thanks!

Comment: The point is that sometimes you cannot get the feets of the perpendiculars if you do not extend the lines